# Hide comments in PhpStorm

Tags: php, comments, phpstorm

I know that it is possible in PhpStorm to remove comments like these with the plus and minus signs on the left:

```
/*
This is
a comment
*/
```

But at the moment, I have some code with these single line comments in it.

```
//Some text explaining the code beneath it
$foo = bar;

//Another piece of text explaining some code
$bar = foo;
```

Is there a shortcut in PhpStorm to hide the single line comments (the ones that are created with "//")? When you have a few of these, it's not really bothering me, but when there are more comments than code, it gets a little bit annoying.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please vote for [IDEA-117927](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117927)

Workarounds:

1.use custom folding regions, like:

```
//region Some text explaining the code beneath it 
//some more text 
//endregion 
$foo = bar;
```

2.change comments color to make them invisible (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106542#comment=27-497674)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is the first time I see YouTrack. Do you now where I can see how many votes there are for this IDEA? And when does this IDEA get picked up by JetBrains?

Comment: @KevinKromjong In this case, the IDEA tag is to note that this is a ticket for the IntelliJ IDEA platform in general, not that it's "an idea". The PhpStorm-specific tag is WI, but since this is a general IntelliJ Platform change, the item is under IDEA. Currently, there are no additional votes (see the "thumbs up" button at the bottom-right of the info box)